# Not able to un-register the tabContainer's Id with Dialog box

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer

I am using dojo 1.8.3.

I am creating a TabContainer inside the dialog box. When the "Go" button is clicked, a dialog box opens having a TabContainer. Now if you close this dialog and reopen it, it will not open because of the allocated widget's ID is not destroyed. I have used the 'destroyRecursive' method to un-register widget's ID but it is not working. Is the implementation error from my side or the because of the library?

In below code I am calling method "getDialog" on button click.

Sample Code: http://jsfiddle.net/55zwt/

**JavaScript**

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"]);

function getDialog() {  
    var placeHolder = dijit.byId('placeHolder');
    if ( placeHolder ) {
        placeHolder.destroyRecursive(true);
    }
    myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "<div id=\"placeHolder\"> </div>",
        style: "width: 500px;height:400px;"
    });
    myDialog.show();
    generateTab();
}

function generateTab() {

    var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
        style: "height: 200px; width: 200px;"
    }, "placeHolder");

    var cp1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
         title: "Food",
         content: "We offer amazing food"
    });
    tc.addChild(cp1);

    var cp2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
         title: "Drinks",
         content: "We are known for our drinks."
    });
    tc.addChild(cp2);

    tc.startup();
    tc.resize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. I have just made modifying in destroyRecursive method. Don't pass anything to destroyRecursive method.    
    `var placeHolder = dijit.byId('placeHolder');
    if ( placeHolder ) {
        placeHolder.destroyRecursive();
    }`

Some modification has been made in library. See below link.

[answer](http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-interest/1219yzgmw0/tabcontainer-controller-destroy-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle does not work :-(

**Solution 1:**

Change the genearteTab() as shown below

```
function generateTab() {

    var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
      id = "tab1", // add this line
      style: "height: 200px; width: 200px;"
    }, "placeHolder");
...
```

Change the getDialog() as shown below

```
function getDialog() {  
    var placeHolder = dijit.byId('tab1'); // replace 'placeHolder' string with 'tab'
...
```

Hope it helps.

**Solution 2:**
I am not sure what was the problem in the above solution. Since I had tried it was working with no errors. Anyway I have tested the below code and it works at my end. Do let me know if you face any issues. Please be a little more elaborate.
You need to change the getDialog() function as below.

```
function getDialog() {

   var placeHolder = dijit.byId('placeHolder');
   if ( placeHolder ) {
      placeHolder.destroyRecursive(true);
   }

   if (typeof(myDialog) !== "undefined" ) { // If its already defined.
      myDialog.set("content","<div id=\"placeHolder\"> </div>");
   } else {
      myDialog = new dialog({
      title: "My Dialog",
      content: "<div id=\"placeHolder\"> </div>",
      style: "width: 500px;height:400px;"
      });
   }

   myDialog.show();

   generateTab();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Sorry but it didn't work as I have to un register the 'placeHolder' id which is allocated by TabContainer.

Comment: I have added another solution (solution 2). Hope it works this time.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. Actually while using "destroyRecursive(true)" it was showing error. I have appended link regarding this bug into my answer.